# missing server hello message in SSL handshake, Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, linux, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

java version 1.8.0_131

nginx configuration here:

```
ssl_certificate      /data/modules/nginx/conf/ssl/pem_file.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key   /data/modules/nginx/conf/ssl/key_file.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

here is java.net debug log:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1654921397 bytes = { 1, 222, 145, 27, 44, 211, 167, 223, 74, 229, 54, 135, 3, 192, 62, 79, 189, 146, 176, 31, 45, 192, 125, 13, 14, 73, 152, 75 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=www.test-api.com]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 200
.......[HEX CONTENT].........
device-state-schedule-1-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 200
[Raw write]: length = 205
.......[HEX CONTENT].........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
device-state-schedule-1-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
device-state-schedule-1-2, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
device-state-schedule-1-2, called closeSocket()
device-state-schedule-1-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2022-12-22 16:47:49.203 DEBUG 99028 --- [te-schedule-1-2] c.x.c.c.l.Logger                         : ContextId [] XlinkPlatformConfigApiRemoteCall#getPlatformConfig(String,String)-<--- ERROR SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (419ms)
2022-12-22 16:47:49.204 DEBUG 99028 --- [te-schedule-1-2] c.x.c.c.l.Logger                         : ContextId [] XlinkPlatformConfigApiRemoteCall#getPlatformConfig(String,String)-javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:83)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.getPlatformConfig(Unknown Source)
    at cn.xlink.service.impl.ChirpStackPlatformConfigServiceImpl.getPlatformConfig(ChirpStackPlatformConfigServiceImpl.java:45)
    at cn.xlink.service.impl.ChirpStackPlatformConfigServiceImpl.getPlatformConfigParams(ChirpStackPlatformConfigServiceImpl.java:63)
    at cn.xlink.service.impl.GatewayDeviceServiceImpl.checkGatewaysDeviceState(GatewayDeviceServiceImpl.java:398)
    at cn.xlink.service.impl.GatewayDeviceServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ecf68591.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at cn.xlink.service.impl.GatewayDeviceServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21970120.checkGatewaysDeviceState(<generated>)
    at cn.xlink.manager.DeviceClientManager.scheduleGatewayState(DeviceClientManager.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

using feign to request other resources and there are no any options on feign and http client

the java application could not access the SSL handshake and there has no server hello message respond from server, any help please?

I try to import the cipher suite [ bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.70.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar ] into the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/ and append the provider [ org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider ] to the java.security in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security also. but it's not work.

`keytool -import -alias "server-ssl" -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file server.cer`

Then I import the server certificate to the java truststore but it's not work yet.

It is ok to open the url on browser and can be accessed by curl or openssl -connect also. It seems only failed on the java application request host:port. I think that might be something wrong on configuring jdk ssl certificate or cipher suite.

How can I check that my server and client configurations are correct?

Comment: *" ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure"* - the server does not like what the client has sent. This might be anything, like no shared cipher, no common protocol version ... - check your server side for possible explanations if possible. If you have something working against this server compare the ClientHello regarding ciphers, version, extensions ...

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich glad to see your comment.  The url can be opened on browser and host:port can be access well by using the openssl -connect also. it seems only failed on using java application to request the host:port

Comment: Given that your Java can only do TLS 1.2 and lower try with `openssl s_client -connect ... -tls1_2` to enforce TLS 1.2. If this works include into your question so that one can see which cipher gets used. If the site is publicly accessible try [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and check what ciphers are supported by the server, then compare it to what Java offers.

Comment: SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 45CC33C48D6AC80FBE5016CC88AB60C4644F65B203334E14BD9C4C8B77C6AE2E
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 0634D8A1FE74A14A48BDF212A91D95548C3A863DC7CA9520CAFFA5B517E5622CFE0300D4C216819149B07A25B022C386
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:

Comment: it use cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 and the cipher is not in java offer list. so i need to import the cipher into the java.security. it seems that importing  org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider into java.security is failed. could you please tell me how to import other cipher suite into the java.security? many thanks

Comment: First you might check if the ciphers support by Java are not supported by the server - use `-cipher` argument in s_client for this but make sure to use the OpenSSL cipher name according to https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES. If you really need to add this cipher - there are many posts here about this topic and if you don't find anything there you might better ask why importing BouncyCastleProvider  fails for you (with sufficient detail)

Comment: I upgrade my java version which support the cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 that java application can request the target url now. Thanks!!!

Comment: Your java was offering only AES-128 and 3DES (112-bit) ciphers, while your nginx is accepting only AES-256 and ChaCha (which in TLS is 256-bit). This was characteristic of old _Oracle and Sun_ (not OpenJDK) packages of Java 8u151 or lower which had 'limited crypto policy' -- you'll find _lots_ of Qs on several stacks from the early teens about this. It was technically possible to download and install 'unlimited crypto policy' (keeping the Java) but upgrading the Java is probably no harder and otherwise better.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am curious about how to find out ciphers that each version provided like you. you may many experience on java SSL or read java document carefully or pay attentioin to java upgrade function in each version? any advice please?

Comment: @Charles_Lau: I'm not sure exactly what you want. I do read documentation when I have a problem, and the release notes for each release; those cover much more than just cryptography. However, this specific issue -- the 'limited' policy -- was very widely discussed and known because it affected _lots_ of people up until 2017; as I said, there are _many_ Stack Qs, and As or just comments, about it, most of which I saw and some of which I participated in.